# Can this shadow be created in CSS?

Tags: css

How can the following dual angled shadow be created in CSS? Is it even possible?

[image]

Comment: i think these would be images - and the css would be positioning near the corners...

Comment: No way to do it in css3 then?

Comment: http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/

Comment: google “advanced box-shadow tricks” next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>​
```

and the following CSS:

```
.box {
    width:70%;
    height:200px;
    margin:40px auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
}
.box:before, .box:after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.box:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}​
```

See this live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/7pgFf/3/)

Comment: Not earlier versions, no. You need to add a bit more

Answer (score 4):

Yes: http://matthamm.com/box-shadow-curl.html

Also: http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/

Comment: the first example in the second link is quite result Hopstream is need

Answer (score 2):

You could put two divs behind the box with a fill and a box shadow. Then rotate each a bit. I would probably do it with an image though, seems cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, with `before` and `after` pseudo-elements.

You position the two absolutely, you rotate them with, let's say 5deg (actually, one with 5 and the other one with -5), you give them each a `box-shadow` and you tweak the spread value such that the shadow appears smaller than the box itself. And you set the `z-index` such that they appear behind your div.

link to demo http://dabblet.com/gist/2789364

relevant part of code

```
.box:before, .box:after {
    bottom: 0;
    min-height: 45%;
    width: 65%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(204,204,204,.4);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    background: rgba(204,204,204,.4);
    content: '';
}
.box:before {
    left: 5px;
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
.box:after {
    right: 5px;
    transform: rotate(5deg);
}
```